# append a new line to a file python

Tags: python, append

I have a file that contains one line

```
car
```

I want to append a new line to the file

when I  used this code:

```
f = open("motors.txt","a")
f.write("Bicycle")
```

I got the following:

```
carBicycle
```

how could I append the new word to a new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix `Bicycle` with a [newline character](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (`\n`) to have it write on a new line:

```
f.write("\nBicycle")
```

Comment: what if Bicycle the first word I want to append in the file?

Comment: In that case, put the newline character at the end of each string that you want to write: `f.write("Bicycle\n")`.